# Take data from Table B if it exists, else keep Table A (following some columns)

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to achieve what's in the example, the idea is to get data from table B if it exists and that with respec to the columns col1=col3 and col2=col4.
not sure wether this is possible or not using SQL

```
col1  col2   
a     b      
c     d    
e     f         

Table B:

col3 col4   
NULL  x      
y     NULL    
NULL  NULL         


Final_Table:

col1  col2   
a     x      
y     d    
e     f
```

Comment: Look at coalesce (https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-basics/db2-coalesce/)

Comment: SQL table is not a spreadsheet, it is a set. There's no *Nth row* in the table, so there's no way to replace *this* row's content with *that* row's content until there's no any common unique identifier.

Comment: Maybe use cursors?

Comment: Your question would seem to presume an ordering of the rows.  But SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: The question does not make sense in a relational database. As @astentx says relational tables are not spreadsheets. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a primary key to compare two or more tables. It is not possible if there is no primary key.

Comment: Any matching rule will do, even if it's an ordering artificial key.